# Determine if this set is a subspace of $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether all polynomials of the form $$ a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x³$$ where $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ are integers, are a subset of $P_3$.

**What I've tried**:

Basically I think I fail to understand what integers in this context means, because in my eyes that makes no difference. Well, I've tried to determine if the set of all polynomials is a subspace by:

- Define a subspace $V$ where the vectors $v, w \in V$
  $$v=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x³$$
  $$w=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x³$$
- Adding vectors, $v+w\in V$ and checking $v+w\in V$
- Multiplicating a scalar $k$, $kv\in V$ and checking $kv\in V$

Am I, like I think, missing something on the question where they state *integers*? Because the set is, according to the answer, not a subspace.

Comment: Hint, scalar multiples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying the polynomial $1$ by the scalar $\frac12$ shows that it is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, that was pretty obvious now. Linear algebra is not my thing, calculus is!